# Use Colorbox within another JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colorbox

Is there a way I can use colorbox to open the links in a JavaScript map I am using on a website? All the links on the site open in colorbox, so far all I can get the map to do is open in a new window with:

```
url_new_tab: 'yes',
```

then the link is:

```
url: "winnipeg.html",
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java is not Javascript

Comment: you could always place the map inside of a div with the css property display:none and on the click event change the display to block.

Comment: that was helpful Luiggi

Comment: Calvin thank you for helping, I should have been more specific, the map is on the homepage and is called up with  <div id="map"></div> the links for the map, if you click on a location a page opens, are within the java, so how would I get them to use the colorbox?